# how to identify if any applications inside docker container as running as root

Tags: docker, doc

We use a lot of 3rd party images [Eg: gitlab , jenkins, centos7 ..] which we run inside our docker containers. I would like to know how to check if any of the applications running in the container is run as root user. Is it the same as checking on a normal server ps -elf|grep root but inside the container.

Answer (score 6):

### Running Containers

To get all processes and their UIDs inside your running containers on a host, you can do the following:

```
for c in $(docker ps -q); do docker inspect $c -f "{{ .Name }}:"; docker top $c | awk '{print $1, $2, $8}'; echo "--------------"; done
```

This will print something like

```
/webserver-dockerized_nginx_1:
UID PID CMD
root 13437 nginx:
systemd+ 13522 nginx:
systemd+ 13526 nginx:
systemd+ 13527 nginx:
systemd+ 13528 nginx:
--------------
```

for all containers you have running.

### Images

To get the configured users for all images on a host you can do

```
docker image inspect $(docker image ls -q) -f "{{ .RepoTags }}: {{ .ContainerConfig.User }} {{ .Config.User }}"
```

This will output something like

```
[nginx:mainline-alpine]:
[memcached:alpine]: memcache memcache
[redis:5-alpine]:
```

As Marvin mentioned: If there is no user in the output, no USER was defined in the Dockerfile, thus the container will run as root (Reference: [Docker Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#user))

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the terminal to your running container and once you're inside you can run the *ps* command:

**Attaching to the container**

```
$ docker exec -it <container_id> /bin/bash
```

You can read more about *docker exec* in the official docs site: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes i am aware of this. But once i connect to the runner container is ps -elf|grep root the only way to check if an application is running as root?

Comment: I think you can do it without grep with: ps -f -u root -U root

Comment: this will not work if there is no shell to attach. docker ps and then docker top <containerid> will show user

Answer (score 1):

You could use *docker top* command in association with the process id... 
Combining "docker ps" and "docker top" could make the thing..

You could do stg like that :

```
docker ps | perl -ne '@cols = split /\s{2,}/, $_; printf "%15s\n", $cols[0]' > tmp.txt &&  tail -n $(($(wc -l < tmp.txt)-1)) tmp.txt | xargs -L1 docker top | perl -ne '@cols = split /\s{2,}/, $_; printf "%15s %65s\n", $cols[0], $cols[7]' && rm tmp.txt
```

That's not a perfect answer ((ould be prettyfied), and also note that it only works for running container. It'd be safer to check this from a image point of view, before you run the container.
Then, every time you get an image, just check this way :

```
d image inspect <image id> | grep -i user
```

I might be wrong, but I think no user means root. Otherwise, you will have to analyse the output there.